# How do I get the first Item from this get?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hi I'm trying to get the first item of a Django Model. How can I get it? I'm looking for the object with the same customer name as the customer (I'm building a webshop btw).

Here is my **model**:

```
class MessageItem(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    mItem = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    mQuantity = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    mOrderItem = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

Here is the **create function**:

```
createModel = MessageItem
for item in items:
    createModel.objects.create(customer=customer, mItem=item.product.name, 
                               mQuantity=str(item.quantity), mOrderItem=str(items))
```

And here is the **Get function**:

```
orderMessage = MessageItem.objects.get(customer=customer)
message_to_send = str(message) + " " + orderMessage
```

Edit:
When I try to run the webshop I get an error:

> store.models.MessageItem.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one MessageItem -- it returned 2!

I have a Model called MessageItem. In that Model I'm saving the Items that the customer added to the cart. After that the Customer clicks on an button "Checkout" and fills in an Email form. Then he send it. And now I want to add the newest row to the email "message" but with the get function I get an error as described in the question

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Its not clear what you are looking for. Please add more information regarding your requirement or issue that you are currently facing

Comment: maybe `MessageItem.objects.filter(customer=customer).first()` do the trick

Comment: I have a Model called MessageItem. In that Model I'm saving the Items that the customer added to the cart. After that the Customer clicks on an button "Checkout" and fills in an Email form. Then he send it. And now I want to add the newest row to the email "message" but with the get function I get an error as described in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
orderMessage = MessageItem.objects.filter(customer=customer).first()
```

get works for single search result and filter works for multiple results